# input output and parsing error in java

Tags: java, io, is-empty

I have two classes where one classes calls upon the other.

Below is a class `Stack` that creates a variable type `stack`

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Stack<Item> {
    private Node first = null;

    private class Node {
        private Item item;
        private Node next;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() { return first == null; }
    public void push(Item item) {
        Node second = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = second;
    }
    public Item pop() {
        Item item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        return item;
    }
}
```

And here, I have a class called `Evaluate`, which calls upon `Stack` and creates a stack based on an input.

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdIn;    
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

    public class Evaluate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> ops = new Stack<String>();
        Stack<Double> vals = new Stack<Double>();
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String s = StdIn.readString();
            if (s.equals("(")) ;
            else if (s.equals("+")) ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals("*")) ops.push(s);
            else if (s.equals(")")) {
                String op = ops.pop();
                if (op.equals("+")) vals.push(vals.pop() + vals.pop());
                else if (op.equals("*")) vals.push(vals.pop() * vals.pop());
            }
            else vals.push(Double.parseDouble(s));
            //When seeing a number, it gets pushed on to the stack
        }
        StdOut.println(vals.pop());
    }
}
```

I've tried two different inputs: `( 1 + ( ( 2 + 3 ) * ( 4 * 5 ) ) )` and `1+2`.

In the first input case, the terminal asks for another input. In the second case, it returns the following error message:

```
   `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1+2"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Evaluate.main(Evaluate.java:18)`
```

I am using `http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr15/cos126/lectures/43stack.pdf` as a resource to learn Java and the codes above are straight from the lecture note.  I have looked at the code and I dont see an obvious mistake (and i think being a lecture note, it probably has none. )

i know that it gets past `isEmpty` because i added `StdOut.println(3);` right below the while conditional (`isEmpty`), and it did print out 3 three times when i input `1 + 2`

Answer (score 0):

`StdIn.readString()` reads a token from standard input, delimited by whitespace. Your second input does not contain any whitespace, and so the whole string is interpreted as a token. `1+2` is not a valid Double, and throws the error you quoted. Try `1 + 2` as input instead

Comment: then the result is the same as `( 1 + ( ( 2 + 3 ) * ( 4 * 5 ) ) )`  it just keeps asking for more inputs.

Comment: Then the test for isEmpty fails. There's probably a whitespace (maybe a newline character?) in the input

Comment: I tried ` 1 + 2 ` and `1 + 2` both. they both keep asking for more inputs

Comment: i know that it gets past `isEmpty` because i added `StdOut.println(3);` right below the while conditional (`isEmpty`), and it did print out 3 three times when i input `1 + 2`